# Equivalence of "können + verb" with infinitive & participle constructs

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive, participle

Under the chapter of “The Infinitive and the participles”, my grammar book<sup>[1]</sup> makes the following comments:

> Page 259:  *sein* ‘be’, as a semi-auxiliary, is the equivalent of
>   *können* (or sometimes *müssen* or *sollen*). The following infinitive has passive force
>
> *a.   **Ist** der Direktor heute **zu** **sprechen**?*
>
> *b.  Die Fahrausweise **sind** auf Verlangen **vorzuzeigen***
>
> Page 272:  Present participles can be used adjectivally with an
>   accompanying *zu*.  This is an adjectival form of the construction
>   with *sein* and an infinitive with *zu* expressing possibility or
>   necessity.  As in that construction the participle has passive force.
>
> *a.   ein nicht **zu** **übersehender** Fehler*
>
> *b.   ihre **anzuerkennende** Leistung*

To understand the equivalence of these constructs, I have constructed two of the examples in modal, infinitive and participle forms.

Example 1:

> Modal form:  *Kann der Direktor heute sprechen*?
>
> sein + zu + infinitive:  ***Ist*** der Direktor heute **zu** **sprechen**? (as
>   above)
>
> *das erste Partizip* with *zu*:  *der **zu** **sprechende** Direktor*

Example 2:

> Modal form: *ein Fehler, den man nicht übersehen kann*
>
> *sein* + *zu* + infinitive:  *Der Fehler **ist** nicht **zu übersehen***
>
> *das erste Partizip* with *zu*:  *ein nicht **zu** **übersehender** Fehler* (as above)

Have I grasped the concept correctly?

Source: “Hammer’s German Grammar and Usage – 3rd Edition”, Martin Durrell, 1996, Arnold.

Comment: The forms in example 1 do not mean the same thing: _kann der Direktor heute sprechen_ means "can he speak today", not "can he be spoken to today". That would be _kann er heute gesprochen werden_, or more conversationally, _kann man heute mit ihm sprechen_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1:

> der **zu sprechende** Direktor

technically correct, but it sounds a bit odd. Germans wouldn't phrase it that way. (Not paticularly sure why)

Example 2:

> Der Fehler **ist** nicht **zu übersehen**

That's completely correct